# XAML datagrid column format duration grater than 24 hours

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid that gets data from a MySQL database and one column represents the total time like `4.22:15:00` (4 days, 22 hours, 15 minutes, 00 seconds)

But I want the output to be `118:15:00` (118 hours, 15 minutes, 00 seconds) or `118:15` is also okay.

I'm using this code for that datagrid column:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="HOURS" Binding="{Binding Hours}" />
```

Which results in:

[image]

I have tried many different possibilities for the StringFormat property like:

```
StringFormat={}{0:hh':'mm}
```

but I couldn't get the desired output...

For the code behind I'm using VB.

Comment: I would suggest not using images in your questions.

Comment: what is the exact type of `Hours` property?

Comment: Not sure you can do that directly with a date, You may need to convert that into a timespan.

Comment: I return the data using a mysql query like this: 

**_SELECT .... SEC_TO_TIME( my_value_here ) AS Hours_**

so I get a "time" value of 118:15:00 but the datagrid shows it as 4.22:15:00 and I can't figure out how to show it as 118:15:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just about parsing the string in an *IValueConverter*:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string str = value as string;
        int idot = str.IndexOf(".");
        int days = int.Parse(str.Substring(0,idot ));
        int idotdot = str.IndexOf(":"); 
        int ho = int.Parse(str.Substring(idot+1, idotdot-idot-1));
        int newho = days * ho; 
        string res = newho.ToString() + str.Substring(idotdot);
        return res;
    }
```

You might need to handle the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the converter. Inside the converter split the data and do your calculation like  days*24+hours...Return string to the grid.